# How to add signature into email (Zend_Mail)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, signature, zend-mail

I need to add a signature to the mail message. `Zend Framework 1.12` and `Zend_Mail` is used.

I think about 2 variants:

1. Simply add sign text into body end, but i think is not good solution.
2. Add new mime part into message, but it seems does not work

How do you think, how to solve this problem?